# How to extract a specific string line

Tags: java, string

I have two elements in my string and I would like to take the second element and put in a new string.

```
String data;
```

The data string contains:

```
27 Nov 2012
30 Oct 2012
```

The two dates are separated by `\n`.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String first = data.substring(0, data.indexOf("\n"));
String second = data.substring(data.indexOf("\n"));
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it:

```
String dates[] = data.split("\n");
String second = dates[1];
```

Comment: I don't think there's any need to escape the backslash in this context.

Comment: @jahroy I know the `split` method takes a regular expression so I thought I would need to.  I could be wrong.

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine without it.  It shouldn't be escaped, because you're not searching for an actual _backslash_ character.  By escaping it, you'd actually be searching for the _backslash_ character followed by an _n_ character (which is not the desired behavior).